# How to allow the user to take a screenshot of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am making a website in WordPress. I want general users to do my exercises. And then be able to record/take a screenshot of the page when completing the exercises. This could then be shared with other media, or be saved to the users computer.

I tried to use this code, but it is not working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".print").click(function() {
    function crateimage(img, selection) {
      //console.log(selection);
      //console.log(img);    
      var canvas = document.getElementById('output');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();
      var imagename;

      //selection.width;
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = selection.width;
        canvas.height = selection.height;
        //alert(selection.width);
        //alert(selection.height);
        //alert(selection.x1);
        //alert(selection.y1);

        context.drawImage(imageObj, selection.x1, selection.y1, selection.width, selection.height, 0, 0, selection.width, selection.height);

        console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        var d = new Date();
        $(".saveimg").attr("href", canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        $(".saveimg").attr("download", "captue" + d.getDate() + d.getDate() + d.getFullYear() + d.getHours() + d.getMilliseconds());
        //  $("#linkimg").attr("href") = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        //<a id="downloadLnk" download="YourFileName.jpg">Download as image</a>

      }

      imageObj.src = img.src;
    }

    html2canvas($(".screen"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {

        var image = new Image();
        var img = '<img id="image_edit" src="' + canvas.toDataURL("image/png") + '">';
        var imgselect;

        //console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        $(".onscreen").html(img).promise().done(function() {
          $(".screen").hide();
          $(".print").hide();
          $(".onscreen").show();
          $(".save").show();

          imgselect = $('#image_edit').imgAreaSelect({
            handles: true,
            instance: true,
            show: true,
            onSelectEnd: crateimage
          });

          //imgselect.setSelection(50,50,200,200);

          $(".save").click(function() {
            imgselect.cancelSelection();
            $(".print").show();
            $(".onscreen").hide();
            $(".screen").show();
            $(this).hide();
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.screenshotbt {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.screen {
  width: 100%;
}

#image_edit {
  line-height: 0;
}

.onscreen {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#output {
  display: none;
}

.save {
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>JS SCREEN SHOT</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="onscreen"></div>
  <div class="screenshotbt print">
    SCREE SHOT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="screenshotbt save" style="display:none;">
    <a class="saveimg" style="color:#fff;display:block;width:100%;" target="_blank">
         กรุณาลากเมาล์เลืกส่วนที่ต้องการ และ กดบันทึก <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="screen">
    <div style="background:#F39C12;text-align:center">
      <div class="container" style="padding:25px;">
        <img src="mac.png" style="max-width:25%">
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="padding:25px;">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>JAVASCRIPT SCREEN SHOT</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="padding:25px;background:#E0E0E0">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>JAVASCRIPT SCREEN SHOT</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="output"></canvas>
</body>
```

I want users to be able to record and download

Comment: Try to include whole path to htm2canvas js